# How to have multiple transaction scopes among Processes

Tags: oracle-apex-23

As in some programming lanuages, for example c#, we can have multiple transaction scopes and those transaction scopes can be committed/rolledback independently.
So how such behavior can be achieved in Oracle Apex?

I have a process (divided logically in multiple processes) where some parts in the beginning are part of final commit (success), few parts are must commit (whether process fails or not) and then few parts are part of final commit (success).

One option would be to put `must commit` parts in the beginning and call `commit` and rest at the end but this will cause program flow illogical so i want to keep the flow intact.